# How to deal with the Perturbed Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

A hamiltonian for one dimensional axis for a particle of mass  m is given by:

$$H_0 = \frac{p^2}{2m} +V(x)$$

Let we apply a term to the hamiltonian:
$$H  = \frac{p^2}{2m} +V(x) + \frac{\lambda}{m} p$$
where p is momentum operator and $\lambda$ , $p$ are constants. 
Therefore the New hamiltonian would become :

$$H  = \frac{(p+ \lambda)^2 }{2m} +V(x) - \frac{\lambda^2}{2m}$$

I have the solution where they write the   perturbed eigenstates as $$\bar{\psi_n } (x)= e^\frac{-ix\lambda}{\hbar} \psi_n (x)$$

How?

It seems that they considered the unperturbed hamiltonian as $$H_0= \frac{(p+ \lambda)^2 }{2m} +V(x)$$

Why is that? I mean why did they include the $\lambda$ term?

Comment: The expression $(x)\exp(-ix \lambda)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the typo.

Comment: I think you completed the square incorrectly in the "new Hamiltonian".

Comment: You have another typo.  The $p$ should be removed from the $-\lambda^2 p / 2m$ term in the second expression for $H$.

Comment: The constant term $-\lambda^2 / 2m$ does not affect the eigenstates.  The new eigenstates can thus be obtained from the old by sending $p \to p-\lambda$.  Such a momentum translation is implemented on position space wave functions with the plane wave factor $e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar}$

Comment: I do understand that the eigenstate doesn't but there would be an energy shift   $\frac{\lambda^2}{2m}$. I'm  confused how they get the perturbed Eigen states mathematically.  Could you please explain a little bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with the Hamiltonian
$$
H = H_0 + \delta H
$$
where
$$ 
H_0 = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)
$$
and
$$
\delta H = \frac{\lambda}{m} p \ .
$$
Moreover, we assume that we know the eigenstates and eigenenergies of $H_0$.  Denote them $\psi_n(x)$ and $E_n$ respectively.  As the questioner has pointed out, we may complete the square to write the Hamiltonian in the form
$$
H = \frac{(p + \lambda)^2}{2m} + V(x) - \frac{\lambda^2}{2m} \ .
$$

The claim, which we will check, is that the eigenstates of $H$ in a position space basis have the form $\tilde \psi_n (x) = e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} \psi_n(x)$.  Recall that in a position space basis, we may write the operator $p = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.  First consider how $p+\lambda$ acts on the shifted wave function:
$$
(p+ \lambda) \tilde \psi_n(x) = \left(\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \lambda \right) e^{-i x \lambda/ \hbar} \psi_n(x) = e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} p \psi_n(x) \ .
$$
Next how $(p+\lambda)^2$ acts:
$$
(p+ \lambda)^2 \tilde \psi_n(x) = (p+\lambda) e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} p \psi_n(x) = e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} p^2 \psi_n(x) \ .
$$
It should then be clear that
$$
H \tilde \psi_n(x) = e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} \left(H_0 - \frac{\lambda^2}{2m} \right) \psi_n(x) = \left( E_n - \frac{\lambda^2}{2m} \right) \tilde \psi_n(x) \ .
$$
Thus the eigenenergies of $H$ are the shifted quantities
$$
\tilde E_n = E_n - \frac{\lambda^2}{2m} \ .
$$

To motivate the factor $e^{-i \lambda x / \hbar}$, it's probably simpler to think about momentum space wave-functions.  Consider the Fourier transform
$$
\phi(p) = \int dx 
\, e^{-i x p / \hbar} \psi(x) \ .
$$
In momentum space, clearly if $\phi(p)$ is an eigenstate of $H_0$, then $\tilde \phi(p) = \phi(p + \lambda)$ is an eigenstate of $H$.  But then we get the chain of equalities
$$
\int dx \, e^{-i x p/ \hbar} \tilde \psi(x) = \tilde \phi(p) =\phi(p+\lambda) = \int dx\,  e^{-i x (p+\lambda) / \hbar} \psi(x) \ .
$$
Multiplying both sides by $e^{i x' p / \hbar}$ and integrating over $p$, we find
$\tilde \psi(x) = e^{-i \lambda x / \hbar} \psi(x)$.

Comment: I understand  that   $\tilde \psi_n (x) = e^{-i x \lambda / \hbar} \psi_n(x)$ ?  satisfies the perturbed eigenstate. But how to guess quick this type of plane wave? Could you help me out of this. I understand the rest of the procedure.